# Preserve leading space when pasting a comment in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

This is something that has been bugging me for a while now. I am currently using Eclipse 3.8. When I paste a comment The space that follows the leading two slashes does not get preserved. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
// comment before cutting and pasting
//^ I want this space preserved
```

When I cut and paste the above comment then this is what it looks like after pasting:

```
//comment before cutting and pasting
//^ space is gone
```

Is there any way to preserve the first space?

PS: Please do not suggest to "upgrade" Eclipse. Version 3.8 is the last version that I can work with. From thereon it got progressively worse.

Comment: In `Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Typing`, turn off "Adjust indentation" in the "When pasting" section.

Comment: @azurefrog So this comes with the tradeoff of losing indentation, which I would like to keep. One would think that adjusting indentation would adjust the slashes instead the first word of the comment.

Comment: Yeah, there's are a bunch of answers floating around SO regarding writing your own formatter rules, but I don't have time at work to find one the would be a good dup for this question, or lacking one that is a good enough fit, write my own answer.  If you're still lacking a response tonight, I'll put something together.